# join data frames and replace one column with another

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames, one with all my data, and another with a corrected ID number for some of the data.

When I attempt to join these values with either a left, inner or full join, I end up with two ID columns (ID.x and ID.y).  Is there anyway to do this so that the ID in my corrected dataset simply replaces the ID in the full dataset?

E.g.,

```
df.full <- left_join(df.full, correctID, 
                     by = c("value"))
```

I've tried both copy = TRUE and FALSE, but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Since it seems that you do not need the column ID from df.full, why not delete it? like: `df.full$ID <- NULL`

Comment: In `correctID` what else exists in the column to pad the rows (NA values?). If the correct ID column just is an updated correct version of df.full, just replace it.

Comment: @JonnyCrunch thanks for that suggestion, that was also the approach taken for the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Update 2023*

`dplyr` has introduced handy functions like `rows_update` that are perfect for this.

```
df.full %>% rows_update(correctID, by = "value")
```

See the `?rows_update` help page for details and other functions in the same family, like `rows_upsert` and `rows_patch`.

---

*Original answer*

There are a few cases:

If you *always* want the value from `correctID`, just drop the `ID` column from `df.full` first:

```
df.full %>%
  select(-ID) %>%
  left_join(correctID, by = "value")
```

If `correctID` isn't complete, and you only want to use it when present:

```
df.full %>%
  left_join(correctID, by = "value") %>%
  mutate(ID = coalesce(ID.y, ID.x)) %>%
  select(-ID.y, -ID.x)
```

You can, of course, reverse that in the opposite case (only want to use `correctID` when `df.full$ID` is missing).

Comment: `correctID[is.na(correctID)] <- df.full[is.na(correctID)]` also works if correctID is padded with NA values.

Comment: @Chabo I assume you mean something more like `df.full$ID[!is.na(correctID$ID)] = correctID$ID[!is.na(df.full$ID)]`, which assumes that `correctID` is padded with `NA`s and in the same row order as as `df.full`? I suppose, but that's a lot of assuming. I'd at least want to use `match` on the `value` column OP joins by to  keep things general (in case `df.full` has repeated  `ID`s, in case rows get shuffled a little... `match` would be more concise than the `dplyr` method, but probably no more efficient.

Comment: @Chabo, thanks for that suggestion.  In my situation, the correctID data frame was not padded with ID values, it was just simply a list of correct IDs, but I can see how your solution would work in a different situation.